# Previous full week from Saturday to Friday

Tags: reporting-services

I need the previous full week in SSRS report builder , but the week is from Saturday to Friday. So the beginning of the working week is Saturday morning 00:01 AM and goes to Friday the following week at midnight.

```
DateFrom=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today)))

DateTo=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today))
```

I have these expressions which work for today, but if I advance the report servers time, it still has previous weeks dates.

I'm not 100% sure if that is the right way of testing this but the report I get has a date time stamp that says saturdays date

eg:
3/17/2018 2:59:20 PM

Comment: Don't advance the server's date to test this, simply change your instance of `Today` to a parameter value you can change.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work , so happy Friday and thanks for the help!
From
   =IIF(Weekday(Today)<7, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 0-WeekDay(Today, 1),     DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today)) , DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -WeekDay(Today), Today))

To=IIF(Weekday(Today)<7, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1-WeekDay(Today), Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6-WeekDay(Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 0, Today)))